# Write pretty multilevel nested if-then-else code in OCaml?

Tags: if-statement, ocaml

In OCaml, if I have to write a function using many if-then-else, below is my stupid and ugly solution.

```
let foo () =
  let a1 = ... in
  if (a1) then
    result1
  else
    let a2 = ... in
    if (a2) then
      result2
    else
      let a3 = ... in
      if (a3) then
        result3
      else
        let a4 = ... in
        if (a4) then
          result4
        else
          result5.
```

How to beautify the code above? I like C/C++ & Java style which use "return" to save indentation of next if-statement.
Can I do the same thing with OCaml?

```
int foo () = {
  bool a1 = ...;
  if (a1)
    return result1;

  bool a2 = ...;
  if (a2)
    return result2;

  bool a3 = ...;
  if (a3)
    return result3;

  bool a4 = ...;
  if (a4)
    return result4;

  return result5;
}
```

Comment: OCaml doesn't have a `return` statement: `if` is probably the way to go. If you get desperate you can split things into another function.

Comment: There is no reason to indent your first example in a ladder. Several editors would indent it vertically

Comment: Some monad libraries in Ocaml define some `return` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `return` statement in OCaml, though you can emulate one with the help of exceptions:

```
exception Ret of t

let my_ret x = raise (Ret x)

let foo () =
 try
  let a1 = ... in
  if a1 then my_ret result1;
  let a2 = ... in
  if a2 then my_ret result2;
  ...
 with Ret x -> x
```

Another helpful solution would be to use lazy evaluation:

```
let foo () =
 let a1 = lazy ...
 and a2 = lazy ...
 and a3 = lazy ...
 in
 match a1, a2, a3 with
 | lazy true, _, _ -> result1
 | _, lazy true, _ -> result2
 | _, _, lazy true -> result3
 | _, _, _ -> result4
```

This is one of the examples using lazy, there probably are more concise way of expressing your calculation.

Answer (score 6):

Core library provides a `with_return` function, that allows you to do a non-local exists from function:

```
open Core_kernel.Std
let foo () = with_return (fun goto -> 
    if a1 then goto.return 1;
    if a2 then goto.return 2;
    if a3 then goto.return 3;
    if a4 then goto.return 4;
    if a5 then goto.return 5;
    return 6)
```

But generally it is better to use pattern-matching or to rethink your code. For example, if you have a list of predicates, and depending on what predicate is true you want to return a value, that means that you can encode this as a search in some mapping structure:

```
let foo () = [
  clause1, expr1;
  clause2, expr2;
  clause3, expr3;
] |> List.Assoc.find true 
  |> Option.value ~default:expr4
```

Of course in this case you do not have short-circuit evaluation. You can fix this with lazy evaluation or with thunks. But unless your computations is really heavy or produce side-effects, its not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` syntactic constructs indeed don't work the same way in *C* and *OCaml*. In *C*, `if` syntax forms are statements, in *OCaml* they are expressions. The closest you get in *C* to *OCaml* `if` is the `?:` ternary operator. If you try to rewrite your C code using this operator instead of `if`, you will face the same challenge. That doesn't mean it's impossible however, as other answers give you solutions.

The simplest one, which works in both languages, is to cut your function body in several sub functions <sup>(*)</sup>, and use continuations:

```
let rec foo () =
  let a1 = … (* computation *) in
  if a1
  then result1
  else foo2 ()
and foo2 () =
  let a2 = … in
  if a2
  then result1
  else foo3 ()
and foo3 () = … (* etc *)
```

It may still be a little cumbersome when writing object methods, but you can always use inner functions to regain "indentation balance" within the method scope.

Also note that the `rec` keyword is there for the sole purpose of allowing each continuation to follow its caller in the source layout, there's no real recursion here.

---

(*): @gsg also mentioned it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `if` expressions, `match` clauses extend to the end of the function even if they contain multiple statements, without needing brackets. So you can do:

```
let foo () =
  match ... with
  | true -> result1
  | false ->
  match ... with
  | true -> result2
  | false ->
  match ... with
  | true -> result3
  | false ->
  match ... with
  | true -> result4
  | false -> result5
```

You didn't show where `result1` comes from in your example, so I can't be sure, but you might find it's better to have the `...` return an option with the result rather than a bool, e.g.

```
let foo () =
  match ... with
  | Some result1 -> result1
  | None ->
  ...
```

Comment: This answer confused me at first, but after looking at the imperative version and thinking for a second... This really does make sense, thanks for the tip!